# ggplot axes are garbled, look like Unicode boxes

Tags: r, ggplot2, nix, nixpkgs

Running Ubuntu 16.04; R 3.6.2; ggplot2 3.3.0

Running R under --nix

If I run this ..

```
library(ggplot2)
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal))
```

I get a plot with little boxes for the axes (Unicode?)

[image: ggplot with garbled axes]

I get the same little boxes if I use 'plot'

*But* If I run 'plot' add a 'family' attribute,

```
plot (1:10, family="arial")
```

I get this (nice axes),

[image: plot gives good axes with 'family' attribute]

This shows that at least *some* fonts are there!

Back to ggplot ....

The easy solution would be to figure out (I tried) how to set the family in ggplot.

I tried,

```
ggplot(heightweight, aes(x= ageYear, y=heightIn, font="ariel")) + geom_point() 
ggplot(heightweight, aes(x= ageYear, y=heightIn, family="ariel")) + geom_point()
```

No help .. Little boxes.
Note: It's happy if I put family="Zombie"

Anyone know how to set the family in ggplot?

A better solution?

The hard solution would be for me to figure out which fonts are missing, install them under --nix, and then make sure R (under --nix) can find them.

Answer (score 2):

After much playing I got something to work!

I now get a beautiful title and axes (no more Unicode).

Here's the snippet

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
   ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
   xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(text=element_text(family="Garamond", size=14))
```

Apparently the way to set the family in ggplot is using 'theme',

```
theme(text=element_text(family="Garamond", size=14))
```

I know it's not a perfect solution but it gets me going (without meds :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be worth renaming this issue because it is a Nix specific issue, and was reasonably hard to find. The core issue is caused by a mismatch between the system fontconfig and the one provided by nix.

https://discourse.nixos.org/t/fonts-in-nix-installed-packages-on-a-non-nixos-system/5871/6

I fixed the issue by adding an explicit `fontconfig` dependency and adding the following to my `mkShell` command

```
shellHook = "export FONTCONFIG_FILE=${pkgs.fontconfig.out}/etc/fonts/fonts.conf";
```

After that opening R from within a nix-shell and generating plots works as expected.